# How to parse JSON from table using redshift

Tags: sql, json, parsing, amazon-redshift

I'm attempting to parse out a json column with multiple nodes of data in the same chunk of json from a table in a relational database. The code I'm using is:

```
SELECT "Id", "LineItemId", "ItemHash"
    , CAST(json_extract_path_text("Analysis", 'FulfillmentOptions', 'Currency', TRUE ) AS Text) AS Currency
    , CAST(json_extract_path_text("Analysis", 'FulfillmentOptions', 'Price', TRUE ) AS Text) AS Price
    , CAST(json_extract_path_text("Analysis", 'FulfillmentOptions', 'Days', TRUE ) AS Text) AS Days
    , CAST(json_extract_path_text("Analysis", 'FulfillmentOptions', 'SpecialDays', TRUE ) AS Text) AS SpecialDays
    , "RequestDate"
FROM "dataset"
```

The columns "Id", "LineItemId", "ItemHash" and "Request Date" are all columns from the table. The new columns "Currency", "Price", "Days" and "SpecialDays" are all created from this transform, but they have no data in them. Below is an example of the data held in the "Analysis" column in the table. There can be up to 7 or 10 chunks of options in each row of the "Analysis" column from the table.

```
{
  "Input": {
    "LineItem": {
      "RefId": "956",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Id": "97961",
      "Agreement": null
    },
    "ShipToAddress": {
      "Street1": "1233 Low Rd",
      "Street2": null,
      "Street3": null,
      "City": "San Jose",
      "StateProvince": "CA",
      "PostalCode": "95129",
      "Country": "US"
    },
    "HandledShipping": false
  },
"FulfillmentOptions": [
      {
        "Currency": "USD",
        "Price": 213.00,
        "Days": 1,
        "SpecialDays": 1,
        "Date": "2021-05-20T00:10:00Z",
        "OtherOptions": {
          "Currency": "USD",
          "OtherInfo": [
            {
              "Id": "1-20210520",
              "Reason": "OneDayOption",
              "Code": "GHHTP9",
              "Cost": 125.69,
              "Date": "2021-05-20T08:00:00"
            },
            {
              "Id": "1-20210520-2",
              "Reason": "TwoDayOption",
              "Code": "6132TPR",
              "Cost": 88.08,
              "Date": "2021-05-20T23:00:00"
            }
          ]
         },
     {
        "Currency": "USD",
        "Price": 300.00,
        "Days": 3,
        "SpecialDays": 3,
        "Date": "2021-05-22T00:10:00Z",
        "OtherOptions": {
          "Currency": "USD",
          "OtherInfo": [
            {
              "Id": "1-20210520-3",
              "Reason": "OneDayOption",
              "Code": "GHHTP9",
              "Cost": 78.69,
              "Date": "2021-05-20T08:00:00"
            },
            {
              "Id": "1-20210520-3-2",
              "Reason": "TwoDayOption",
              "Code": "ZZZDR1",
              "Cost": 79.42,
              "Date": "2021-05-22T23:00:00"
            }
          ]
         },
And so on....
```

Any ideas on what may be wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

"FulfillmentOptions" is an array and you need to index into an array element before extracting the "Currency" text.

Comment: I see. I added a line (see below), but when I ran it, it created a new column, with no data once again. I could totally be using the function wrong though.
---
New Line: json_extract_array_element_text("Analysis", 1, TRUE) AS FulfillmentOptions
---

Comment: I believe you have to give this function the extracted text of the array, FullfillmentOptions. This function operates on the array portion. Once you get the array element you will need to extract the text for the element in question. You will need to nest 3 functions.

Comment: Okay, do you know how I would extract the array element, I think that is the piece I'm missing.

Comment: Start by extracting the text for FullfillmentOptions array and check to see if it is correct.  Then extract the first element of this array by using the first result as the source of the array extract function.  Then use this result to extract the text for the value you want.  Take it one step at a time, checking as you go.